# Office 365 users Email activity in Graph api

Tags: graph, office365

I am writing an application to get email acitivity summary information for Office365 using Graph APi. i have successfully done the same but i cannot get the latest data of users e.g. of same date or -1 or -2 days. What date does graph store data exactly? Is there any other way to get this activity summary data of Office365.